# How to display best seller products on front-page using Shopify

Tags: shopify

I have a dev theme for a shopify store. Basically it's a child theme. I would like to get how to display the best selling products on the front page. I tried something like this but no luck maybe because the sample is outdated.

```
<div class="row">
  {% for product in collections["all"].products | limit:12 | sort_by: 'best-seller' %}
    {% include 'product-grid-item' with "all" %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Is there any way we can create something like this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way of doing it, as `sort` on Shopify won't work with the value `best-seller`, is to create a new Collection called (for example) **Best Sellers** where you have all your products (you could set as the sole condition for product price to be greater than $0 if it applies on your store).

Then, set that collection sorting to `By best selling` on your admin dashboard.

[image: admin dashboard]

Finally, use Liquid in a similar way as per the following:

```
<div class="row">
  {% for product in collections.best-sellers.products | limit:12 %}
    {% include 'product-grid-item' with "all" %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try this one.